# Return child class into base class object

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my head around some inheritance problem in C++:

Consider a base class `Foo()` with a method `method()` and its derived class `Bar`. Now I override the method in `Bar`.

```
class Foo{
public:
    double method();
}

class Bar public: Foo
{
public:
    double method()
}
```

And a function like this:

```
Foo get_bar(){
    Bar bar()
    return bar
}
```

Calling the function `get_bar()` I'd like to be able to call `Bar::method()`

```
Foo foo = get_bar();
foo.method() (-> which should be Bar::method)
```

Is this possible? And if, how? I think I am making a fundamental mistake here which I don't see. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please use proper syntax for your example: `Bar(){ public: Foo` this is incorrect (there's a few more like missing return types and semicolon)

Comment: Is making `method` virtual an option? Because this is the exact reason virtual methods exist.

Comment: To create a Bar object you shouldn't put the ()'s after the variable name - the compiler will think you're declaring a function - which catches me out from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want `get_bar()` to return a child class `Bar` as if it was the base class `Foo` such that you can subsequently call `method` on it and it will call `Bar::method()`. Yes, you can do that. It is called **Polymorphism**.

In order to achieve this `get_bar()` needs to return a pointer otherwise you will encounter the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and won't get the polymorphic behaviour you are looking for. As `get_bar()` is a factory function transferring ownership to the caller it is preferable to return a smart-pointer like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> getBar() {
    return std::make_unique<Bar>();
}
```

`Foo::method()` needs to be `virtual` in order to override it in `Bar`. And in order to destroy `Bar` properly when the `Foo` pointer is deleted `Foo` must have a virtual destructor:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    virtual void method();
    virtual ~Foo(){}
};

class Bar : public Foo {
  public:
    void method() override;
};
```

Comment: As @Mike Seymour pointed out for `C++11` compilers use: `return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Bar);`

Answer (score 3):

To override (not overwrite) a function, it must be virtual:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void method();
    virtual ~Foo() = default;  // technically optional, but usually needed
};
```

For completeness, here is the corrected syntax for the derived class:

```
class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    void method() override;  // override is optional, but a good idea
};
```

Polymorphism only works on references and pointers, so your function would have to return one of those, not a base-class object. As it is (once the syntax is fixed), it *slices* the `Bar` object to return a copy of its `Foo`, which would not give you the overridden function that you want.

There's no existing object to return a reference to; so you'll probably have to dynamically create one an return a pointer. Unless you enjoy long debugging sessions, use smart pointers to manage dynamic objects:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> get_bar() {
    return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Bar); // C++14: make_unique<Bar>();
}
```